# MongoDB Indexing that can sort documents on basis certain property empty or not

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

**Mongo Schema--**

```
let community = new schema({
   event_id: { type: Number, required: true },
   industry: { type: String, default: "" },
   intrests: [{ type: String, default: [] }],
   look: {
     lookingFor: { type: String, default: "" }
     },
   offer: {
     offering: { type: String, default: "" }
     }
   })
```

**Mongo Find Query --**

```
    const query = {
           event_id : 845
    }

    const projection = {
        look : 1,
        offer : 1,
        industry : 1,
        intrests : 1
    }

    const options = { lean : true }

    models.community.find(query, projection, options, function (err, data) {
        console.log('Data ----', data)
     })
```

**OUTPUT IS --**

```
{ _id: 5a09ac3d936a8c707f371234,
industry: 'ind 4',
intrests: [ 'int 3' ],
look: { lookingFor: 'lk 4' },
offer: { offering: 'lk 4' } },
{ _id: 5a09f543936a8c707f3a1fd0,
industry: 'ind 3',
intrests: [ 'int 1' ],
look: { lookingFor: 'lk 4' },
offer: { offering: 'lk 4' } },
{ _id: 5a0a85cf936a8c707f3f6d23,
look: { lookingFor: 'mak' },
offer: { offering: 'mak' },
industry: 'IT',
intrests: [ 'sdsdsdsd' ] },
{ _id: 5a0d65d0936a8c707f5b2e05 },
{ _id: 5a0e78d4936a8c707f655598 },
{ _id: 5a108e52936a8c707f7dea45 },
{ _id: 5a1425dd936a8c707fa9f79b },
{ _id: 5a155ec6936a8c707fb905d0 },
{ _id: 5a16627b936a8c707fc58f64 },
{ _id: 5a16aed9936a8c707fc8f133,
look: { lookingFor: 'mak' },
industry: 'Events',
intrests: [ null, null, null, null ] },
{ _id: 5a17cd0e936a8c707fd6c09c },
{ _id: 5a17cee4936a8c707fd6d5c5 },
{ _id: 5a17cf11936a8c707fd6d7b3 },
{ _id: 5a17eb87936a8c707fd80e92 }, 
{ _id: 5a1bf7bd936a8c707f09297f },
{ _id: 5a1c8948936a8c707f0febb5 },
{ _id: 5a1ef697936a8c707f2d03ed },
{ _id: 5a2690ee936a8c707f8c18b6, industry: 'App Development' }
```

See some of them are empty and The query I'm using will search or go through all documents in the collection.

**My Question is--**

I want only those document in which look & offer is not empty **efficiently**.

**Efficient Idea:** Is there any way of doing indexing, put all the those documents whose look and offer are empty go in last i.e. only those who have data present, put on starting(Like descending order). And I can traverse only starting document.

For example there are 10,00,000 users, out of them only 1000 users fill there look & offer field. But when I apply find method it will traverse full document.

Comment: use `$exists` query operator... `db.collection.find({ look: { $exists:true }, offer: { $exists: true }})`

Comment: But it will also traverse the whole collection (10 lakh users). I want to loop through(traverse) only 1000 users.

Comment: Then create indexing on `look` and `offer` field

Comment: I tried this but its not working.

Comment: Can you show what `.explain()` argument shows

Comment: It is doing COLLSCAN.

-> db.communities.createIndex({look : -1})

->"queryPlanner" : {
 "plannerVersion" : 1, "namespace" : "demodb.communities", "indexFilterSet" : false, "parsedQuery" : { "event_id" : {"$eq" : 54321}},
 "winningPlan" : { "stage" : "PROJECTION", "transformBy" : {"look" : 1,"industry" : 1},
 "inputStage" : { "stage" : "COLLSCAN", "filter" : { "event_id" : {"$eq" : 54321}},"direction" : "forward"}},"rejectedPlans" : [ ]}